# What distributed filesystem / DB on Amazon EC2 for an enterprise app?

Tags: web-applications, amazon-ec2

I am going to write an enterprise app using Amazon EC2. It has to use distributed / redundant filesystems / DB in order to guarantee data safety and good availability. I've seen that Amazon provides some solutions, like SimpleDB. But it doesn't seem good enough to be used with, say, Spring. I was thinking of mysql cluster, is it any good? Would you recommend it?

Also, tell what would be you your best choices in this situation

Answer (score 0):

As for database, you can probably use [Amazon's RDS service](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/), which currently offers you MySQL and there's plans to add Oracle in the short term.

As for the filesystem, that would probably depend on the needs of your application. If it's going to be very data-intensive, you could probably setup a Hadoop filesystem, if it needs only to be distributed, something like AFS could do the trick. If reliability and availability are your top requirements, probably the underlying S3 storage service already offers those attributes to you, so you may even manage to use EBS volumes over the S3 storage.